# Ubuntu 12.04 Upgrade

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I Upgraded From 11.10 to 12.04 but as I left the computer on for the download the power supply was cut down by a power breakdown so when i turned on ubuntu it said there was a partial upgrade and there was this error and they told me to do this

sudo apt-get install -f

and after that the upgrade manager started installing 12.04 and when it was done and i restarted it was odd like this was like a in between

i couldnt resize the launcher
tomboy and banshee are still here
the hud is there

so now im stuck between two versions

please help me out of this mess

i do have the 11.10 live cd should i try it first

Comment: What was the output of that command you entered? After the command, did you do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. The issue may have been caused by a custom unity instances, I tried reverting but that did not really help. So I ended up `sudo apt-get install -f` which appeared to have fixed the issue.